# Is it possible to fix the fuzziness of antialiased SKShapeNodes?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm experimenting with using SKShapeNodes in a game, and have found that antialiased SKShapeNodes are very blurry.

Without antialiasing:

[image: image without antialiasing]

With antialiasing:

[image: image with antialiasing]

Is there some way to use antialiasing of SKShapeNodes in SpriteKit to reduce the stair-stepping on lines, but without making the lines blurry as in the second image above?

Answer (score 5):

Nope—that’s what “antialiasing” looks like on a shape node. You might be expecting to see something more like [multisampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisampling), but that’s not what SpriteKit is doing here. To get the smooth non-blurry lines you’re looking for you’ll have to draw your shapes into an image and then display that in an SKNode. You might also consider [filing an enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com) on the API.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pretty solution, but it does work: Create a bigger SKShapeNode and scale it down.

Normal:

```
let shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
```

Scaled:

```
let scaleFactor: CGFloat = 2
let shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10 * scaleFactor)
shape.xScale = 1 / scaleFactor
shape.yScale = 1 / scaleFactor
```

This makes the render appear much less fuzzy, but **be warned**, it can cause frustrating issues when adding SKNodes as children, because they may be recursively scaled and end up smaller than you expect.