# Swift and SpriteKit: how to implement non-fuzzy circle timer with SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The code below implements a circle timer with SKShapeNode where one slice of the circle vanishes as time ticks off.

Unfortunately, the timer is fuzzy because of limitations with SKShapeNode.

[Answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013830/is-it-possible-to-fix-the-fuzziness-of-antialiased-skshapenodes) did not address the issue, and also were old and may no longer apply.

1) Is there a way to use SKShapeNode without such fuzzy lines?

2) If there is no way to fix SKShapdeNode, what are the alternatives for implementing a similar circle timer?

```
    let timer = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(50))
    timer.fillColor = UIColor.red
    timer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear
    timer.lineWidth = 0
    timer.zRotation = CGFloat.pi / 2

    timer.path = self.circle(radius: CGFloat(50), percent: CGFloat(90))

fileprivate func circle(radius: CGFloat, percent: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
    // Adjust <percent> if less than 0
    let percent = percent < 0 ? 0 : percent

    // Generate circle path
    let start = CGFloat(0)
    let end = CGFloat.pi * 2 * percent
    let center = CGPoint.zero
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: center)
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter:center, radius: radius, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: center)

    // Return path
    return bezierPath.cgPath
}
```

Comment: Set a stroke color other than clear with a line width.

Comment: @ElTomato could you post as an answer? That seems to work in preliminary testing!

Answer (score 1):

Shaders will probably accomplish what you want, check out http://battleofbrothers.com/sirryan/understanding-shaders-in-spritekit/

Also, SKShapeNode should not be used outside of debugging according to AppleDocs, have ran into a few issues using them in the past.

Comment: What is your source that claims SKShapeNodes are only for debugging purposes?  That is definitely not the case.  They should be used sparingly because they are resource intensive.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I guess I'm reading a bit inbetween the lines here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode . "Shape nodes are useful for content that cannot be easily decomposed into simple textured sprites. Shape nodes are also very useful for building and displaying debugging information on top of your game content. However, the SKSpriteNode class offers higher performance than this class, so use shape nodes sparingly." To me, it sounds like its good for debugging but SKSpriteNode is a better alternative. Of course, you cant do all the same things with SpriteNode.

Comment: that is just telling you it is great for debugging, which it is, like making wireframes.  There are situations where SKShapeNode is better than SKSpriteNode.  For example, to draw a squiggle when you touch the screen, you just update the path of the SKShapeNode.  To make it with an SKSpriteNode requires updating textures

Answer (score 1):

@ElTomato mentioned setting a stroke color and line width,  this will work in masking the fuzziness.

A better solution may be to just turn off anti-aliasing with `isAntialiased = false`

This would depend on your graphic preference of course.

Comment: unfortunately `antialiased = false` didn't work, only answer from @ElTomato did. did `antialiased = false` work for you?

Comment: @Crashalot I do not know what you were doing to give you a definitive response.

Comment: If you use the code above and only change `antialiased = false` does the timer come out as sharp for you?

Comment: first, the code you posted doesn't even work because you have a path intersecting itself, which SKShapeNode cannot handle.  Did you mean 0.90 for percentage?  Second, what is the scene size? because you shouldn't even notice any blur at such a high resolution

Comment: sorry, you're right, replaced variables with fixed values while posting the question. it should be 0.90 for percent. scene size is the device size, so 375x667 for iphone 7 which we tested on.